# pg_basebackup fails with " too many connections for role "replication""

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-basebackup

I am trying to set up a standby server and keep getting this error. My primary server has more than enough connections to handle the load:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 10
max_connections=100
checkpoint_segments = 8
wal_keep_segments = 8
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/archive/%f'
```

This is the command that fails on the standby server:

```
pg_basebackup -h ${MASTER_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR} -D ${PGDATA} -U ${REP_USER} -vPw --xlog-method=stream
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Check `pg_roles.rolconnlimit` for `rolname='replication'`

Comment: you're right. The value is set to 1. But how do I change it? It's a view and not writable!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per comments, `pg_roles.rolconnlimit` is set to `1` for that role so it needs to be increased a bit to allow for several simultaneous connections.

Choose a more reasonable value, say `5` (or `-1` for unlimited) and issue as superuser:

```
ALTER ROLE replication CONNECTION LIMIT 5;
```

...or connect with a different database user for `pg_basebackup`.